# Using datetime format via Yii2-formatter

Tags: php, datetime, yii2, date-formatting

I have problem with using Yii2-formatter. My config 
is

```
    'formatter' => [
        'class' => 'yii\i18n\Formatter',
        'defaultTimeZone' => 'Asia/Novosibirsk',
        'timeZone' => 'Asia/Novosibirsk',
        'currencyCode' => 'RUB',
        'locale' => 'ru_RU',
        'dateFormat' => 'php:d.m.Y',
        'timeFormat' => 'php: H:i:s',
        'datetimeFormat' => 'php:d.m.Y H:i',
    ],
```

When I try

```
echo Yii::$app->formatter->asDateTime('15-06-2014 14:10:10');
```

it work correct - show 15.06.2014 14:10.
When I try

```
echo Yii::$app->formatter->asDateTime('15-06-2015 14:10:10');
```

it work not correct - show 15.06.2015 15:10. When I set year 2016, it works not corrected too. I try to

```
echo date('d.m.Y H:i', strtotime('15-06-2015 14:10:10'))
```

And it works correct for 2015 and 2016 years, PHP-config is right. Could anyone help, what's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's related with returning to standard time all year in Russia in 2014 year (October, 26). See [this article](http://www.timeanddate.com/news/time/russia-abandons-permanent-summer-time.html) for reference:

> Most Russians will move to permanent Standard Time, or “winter time”,
>   by setting their clocks 1 hour back on October 26, 2014. This is the
>   same date most Europeans end Daylight Saving Time (DST).

Check you `date.timezone` setting in `php.ini` config and PHP version used, seems like it was fixed in later versions.

Also check `tzdata` and `pecl timezonedb`.

Maybe [this forum discussion](http://phpclub.ru/talk/threads/time-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE.78023/) will be helpful too, even it's in russian.